# Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

Tags: angular, github, angular-ui-router, node-sass

Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

Also run the commands,

sudo npm install node-sass --save

sudo npm rebuild node-sass --force

Still showing the same error. Anyone pls help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common issue

**`Step 1 :`** Try removing the node_modules directory

**`Step 2:`** Install with the command

**`npm i`**

Comment: run it as a admin

Comment: how to run it as admin?

Answer (score 34):

There are two things you can do to fixed this issue.

```
1) npm rebuild node-sass --force 

2) npm install node-sass
```

This both command will fixed your `node-sass` issue.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error and this command fix my issue.
`sudo npm install --save-dev --unsafe-perm node-sass`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
But I was too lazy to read the NPM feedback.

So... I was missing **--scripts-prepend-node-path**.
Simple ran:

```
npm install --scripts-prepend-node-path
```

and

```
npm run watch --scripts-prepend-node-path
```

All good.

Answer (score 0):

try these :

Windows users

set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Mac users

export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider